How to detect folder file upload in Minio with Redis
I have this architecture:

Basically:

user will upload in Minio bucket, a new folders with set of files
I will require to add those file to a new queue in redis
a DAG is triggered every X min to check new files in the queue to process with some ETL steps into DB

My challenge is related on how Minio is handling the files/folder upload: I will require to process the queue ONLY when all files are uploaded in each folder. Folders name is created by end-user and will change.
At the moment I've configured the event in Minio:
mc admin config set myminio notify_redis:1 address="redis:6379" key="minio_notifications" format="namespace"
mc admin service restart myminio
mc event add myminio/test arn:minio:sqs::1:redis --event put 

But I cannot efficently manage the processing as DAG task shall run ONLY when all files are uploaded in each folders.
Is there any efficient way to monitor bucket-folder file upload activity in Minio? or some better approach?
Thx
